# C program to list hidden and read only files

Tags: c, linux

I'm creating a simple C program that list directory contents.  Does anyone know how to list only hidden?  The folllowing code pulls every file from the directory and works perfect, but I only need the hidden files.  Thanks.

Comment: The phrase "hidden file" is almost meaningless.  It basically means "those files with names that are not listed by default by whatever tool you are using to print the names".  A common convention is to suppress names beginning with `.`, but if you are writing the software that prints the names, then you get to decide what a "hidden file" is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On GNU/Linux, a hidden file begin with a dot.

```
#include <string.h>

int is_hidden(const char *name)
{
  return name[0] == '.' &&
         strcmp(name, ".") != 0 &&
         strcmp(name, "..") != 0);
}
```

To check if a file is read-only, it could be a good idea to use the `stat` function.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_readonly(const char *name)
{
  struct stat buf;

  stat(name, &buf);

  return buf->st_mode & /* ... */;
}
```

Comment: As the comment above explains, "hidden file" is really a shell/ls convention.

Answer (score 3):

- To decide if a file is "hidden" check if its name begins with a `.`
- To decide if a file is read-only do a `stat(2)` and check permissions (`st_mode`)

Alternatively, for the second point you could use `access(2)` if you're careful. If you want to `open(2)` that file you shouldn't trust whatever `access(2)` returned. Generally `access(2)` is to be avoided.

Comment: The reason to avoid access is the TOCTOU (Time of Check/Time of Use) type of problem: You check for something, somebody sneaks in and changes it, then you rely on the (now stale) data collected. That isn't a problem if you just check.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a file is readonly or not, you can use sys/stat.h (reference : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)

All you need to do is to perform & (binary and) operation on st_mode.

```
struct stat st; 

if (stat(fileName, &st) == 0)
    cout << " user write permission: " << (st.st_mode & 00200 ) ;
```

If the output is 0, then user has no permission to write (readonly). Otherwise the file is not readonly.

Other permission bits:

```
       S_IRWXU     00700   mask for file owner permissions
       S_IRUSR     00400   owner has read permission
       S_IWUSR     00200   owner has write permission
       S_IXUSR     00100   owner has execute permission
       S_IRWXG     00070   mask for group permissions
       S_IRGRP     00040   group has read permission
       S_IWGRP     00020   group has write permission
       S_IXGRP     00010   group has execute permission
       S_IRWXO     00007   mask for permissions for others
                           (not in group)
       S_IROTH     00004   others have read permission
       S_IWOTH     00002   others have write permission
       S_IXOTH     00001   others have execute permission
```

Answer (score -2):

Below code snippet will help you to check whether the file is hidden or not in windows.

```
int is_hiddenfile(char* file_name)
{
    FILE * batch_file = NULL;
    FILE * output_file = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    batch_file = fopen ("D:\\bat.bat", "w");
    fputs ("dir /ah ", batch_file);
    fputs (file_name, batch_file);
    fputs (" 2>D:\\out.txt", batch_file);
    fclose (batch_file);
    ShellExecuteA (NULL, "open", "D:\\bat.bat", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    output_file = fopen("D:\\out.txt", "r");
    while(feof(output_file) == 0)
    {
        fgetc(output_file);
        count++;
    }
    if (count <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

To check whether a file is readonly or not in windows, `/ar` needs to be used instead of `/ah` in `dir` command.

```
int is_readonlyfile(char* file_name)
{
    ... //same as is_hiddenfile function
    fputs ("dir /ar ", batch_file);
    ... //same as is_hiddenfile function
}
```

Comment: The question was tagged *Linux* and your answer does not apply for Linux.

Comment: Not only that, but the suggestion is to create a brand new file at the root of the D drive called `bat.bat` (does the user have such a drive and write access there? Who knows?) which calls the shell `dir` command asking for hidden files and seeks the one being sought, pipes the output to a file called `out.txt` then checks whether it has contents. It then leaves both the batch file and its piped output files in place. So it's a very convoluted way of querying, and won't even necessarily work.